# "Why [subject] is [property]" VS. "Why is [subject] [property]" in a title

Tags: word-order, questions, headline-case

I'm struggling to appropriately choose between these two alternatives. It will be a title in a presentation I'm making, where [subject] can be "dogs" and [property] can be "great" for example.

The title page should not feel to the reader as myself asking the question, but should rather pose as a introduction to an answer I'm about to give. So, in that case, is it correct to use "Why dogs are great" or "Why are dogs great"?

EDIT: I'm more inclined to use the first variant, but somehow it feels weird.

Comment: *Why are Dogs Great?* asks the reader that question and signals that the answer is coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you title it *Why is X Y?* you are asking a question. The audience may expect that you will end up by answering the question, but if you conclude that you cannot, or need not at present, you are not failing to deliver what you offered.

If you title it *Why X is Y*, you are offering a construct that is normally embedded in a clause with a main verb such as *know* or *understand*, or *explain*. It is true that you could embed it after *ask* or *investigate*, in which case it might remain as a question; but in many cases it represents not a question but an answer (or explanation). Thus if you use this title, you are implicitly telling the reader that you are going to give an answer; and if you don't, you might be seen as breaking faith with the reader.